# SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'fresh_start.event' doesn't exist (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `event`)

Tags: php, laravel

I am a newbie in Laravel.

So I have this problem when I try to update my form, the error SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'fresh_start.event' doesn't exist (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `event` where `title` = eqwee) comes out.

It's weird since all the other function inside the EventController works well, except the update function that returns the error code above.

**Event Model**

```
class Event extends Model
{
//
protected $fillable = ['title', 'objective', 'date', 'venue', 'description', 'slug'];

public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'slug';
}
}
```

**Event Controller**

```
class EventController extends Controller
{
  public function update(Request $request, Event $event)
{
   //
   $validated = $request->validate([
        'title' => 'required|string|unique:event|min:5|max:100',
        'objective' => 'required|string|min:5|max:2000',
        'date' => 'required|string|min:5|max:2000',
        'venue' => 'required|string|min:5|max:2000',
        'description' => 'required|string|min:5|max:2000'
    ]);

    // Create slug from title
    $validated['slug'] = Str::slug($validated['title'], '-');

    // Update Post with validated data
    $event->update($validated);

    // Redirect the user to the created post woth an updated notification
    return redirect(route('events.edit', [$event->slug]))->with('notification', 'Event updated!');

}
```

**Edit Blade Page**

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('events.update', [$event->slug]) }}">

                    @csrf
                    @method('patch')
                    @include('partials.errors')

                    <div class="field">
                        <label class="label">Title</label>
                        <div class="control">
                            <input type="text" name="title" value="{{ $event->title }}" class="input" placeholder="Title" minlength="5" maxlength="100" required />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="field">
                        <label class="label">Objective</label>
                        <div class="control">
                            <textarea name="content" class="textarea" placeholder="Content" minlength="5" maxlength="2000" required rows="10">{{ $event->objective }}</textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="field">
                        <label class="label">Date</label>
                        <div class="control">
                            <input type="text" name="title" value="{{ $event->date }}" class="input" placeholder="Title" minlength="5" maxlength="100" required />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="field">
                        <label class="label">Venue</label>
                        <div class="control">
                            <input type="text" name="title" value="{{ $event->venue }}" class="input" placeholder="Title" minlength="5" maxlength="100" required />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="field">
                        <label class="label">Description</label>
                        <div class="control">
                            <textarea name="content" class="textarea" placeholder="Content" minlength="5" maxlength="2000" required rows="10">{{ $event->description }}</textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>



                    <div class="field">
                        <div class="control">
                            <button type="submit" class="button is-link is-outlined">Update</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </form>
```

Thank you for your time!

**UPDATE**

So I noticed that when I try to dump the $request variable in controller. the request parameter is not the one that I wanted. And I'm not sure on how to change it.

From the picture I attached below, it only have 2 variables (title, content), which the one I needed was actually 5 (title, objective, date, venue, description).
Any idea, guys?[image]

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Does the table in question exist after all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is occuring because in Event Model you have not mentioned tablename and its primary key. Which are neccessary if you want to use Eloquent ORM.

Comment: I've already added the tablename, still nothing changes. But one thing I notice that my database tablename is "events", while the error says that Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'fresh_start.event'. The tablename in the error doesn't have an 's' behind it. But I don't know how to configure it, as it won't change to the correct one.

Comment: First does the table events really exists in your database? Second, in validation of update method you have mentioned like this "required|string|unique:event|min:5|max:100" , here it should be "unique:events" because your table is events.

Comment: The latter one fixed it! Thank you for your help, brother!